# Problems with RegionBoundary and RegionIntersection

Tags: regions

I'm trying to get an intersection boundary of a prism's surface and a plane:

```
prism = Entity["Polyhedron",{"Prism", 6}]
plane = InfinitePlane[prism["VertexCoordinates"][[{4, 6, 11}]]]

RegionIntersection[plane, prism["ImplicitRegion"]]
```

`DiscretizeRegion` turns it into 2D face, but I can't for the life of me extract the boundary of it. `RegionBoundary` doesn't work, it works as an identity and doesn't lower region's dimension. I've also tried everything with `prism["MeshRegion"]` and `prism["BoundaryMeshRegion"]`.

Comment: Wow, I was going to suggest you use the method described [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137126/9490) to get the intersection - and it would in principle work.  But if you execute `Length[MeshPrimitives[
  EntityValue[
   Entity["Polyhedron", {"Prism", 6}],
   "MeshRegion"],
  2]
 ]` you see that the mesh region for this entity has almost 24,000 polygons!

Comment: @JasonB. It kinda works `Cases[RegionIntersection[plane, #] & /@ 
  MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeGraphics@prism["Faces"], 2], _Line]`, not exactly perfect, but good enough...

Comment: Still would love some `Region` solution, discretizing graphics feels wrong to me

Comment: in general `Region` functions don't work for 3D regions as well.  You can tweak your solution to give a polygon, `polygon = 
  Cases[RegionIntersection[plane, #] & /@ 
      MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeGraphics@prism["Faces"], 2], 
     Line[{a_, b_}] :> 
      Sequence[a, b]] // (#[[Last@FindShortestTour[#]]] &) // 
   Polygon;
Graphics3D@polygon`

Comment: @JasonB. Luckily for us, the `"BoundaryMeshRegion"` property gives us a region with a minimal amount of polygons. We can get a `MeshRegion` from this with only 12 tetrahedron with `TriangulateMesh[prism["BoundaryMeshRegion"], MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity]`.

Answer (score 3):

A potential work around is to express this region in terms of graphics regions.

```
prism = Entity["Polyhedron", {"Prism", 6}];
plane = InfinitePlane[prism["VertexCoordinates"][[{4, 6, 11}]]];

pts = prism["VertexCoordinates"];

prisms = Prism[pts[[#]]] & /@ {{1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6}, {5, 9, 11, 6, 10, 12}, 
  {7, 3, 11, 8, 4, 12}, {3, 5, 11, 4, 6, 12}};

Graphics3D[prisms]
```

[image]

```
ints = RegionIntersection[#, plane] & /@ prisms
```

> ```
> {
>   Line[{{-1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}, {-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}}], 
>   Triangle[{{-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2, -1/6}, {1, 0, -1/2}}], 
>   Triangle[{{-1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}, {1, 0, -1/2}, {1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2, -1/6}}], 
>   Triangle[{{-1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}, {-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}, {1, 0, -1/2}}]
> }
> ```

```
final = Polygon[Rest[ints][[All, 1]]];

Graphics3D[final]
```

[image]

At this point one could figure out a way to merge the three triangles into a 5 sided polygon.